# If $f(\cdot,y)$ is measurable and $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous, $\{x:|f(x,y)-f(x,0)| \leq \epsilon, \; \;\forall y <\delta\}$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $\mu(X) < \infty$ and $f : X \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ is a function such that $f(\cdot,y)$ is measurable for each $y \in [0,1]$ and $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous for each $x \in X$. Show that the set $$E=\{x:|f(x,y)-f(x,0)| \leq \epsilon, \; \; \forall y <\delta\}$$ is measurable.

The exercise is from Folland's Real Analysis (Chapter 2, ex. 43).

I thought about the set $A= E \times [0,\delta)$. If $(x,y) \in A$, then $|f(x,y)-f(x,0)| \leq \epsilon$. But it seems to be useless. I need your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V =\{y_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\} $ be a dense set in the interval $[0,\delta)$ then $$E=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n $$ where $$E_n =\{x: | f(x,y_n ) -f(x,0)|\leq \varepsilon\}$$ and the sets $E_n$ are obviously measurable.